# Getters in Kotlin: Purpose of the get-keyword

Tags: kotlin

If I execute this code ...

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    class Foo {
        val check: Boolean get() = 3 % 2 == 0
    }

    val f = Foo()
    println(f.check)
}
```

... then it works and false is returned.

When I do this (leaving get() out) ...

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    class Foo {
        val check: Boolean = 3 % 2 == 0
    }

    val f = Foo()
    println(f.check)
}
```

... then the result is the same.

**What's the actual purpose of the get-Keyword?**

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### In the first code:

Getter is a function and the field is not actually stored, its a dummy field works as a function, and result is computed at the time of call of getter i.e. when we call check.

Use of this type of getter is useful in calculating runtime properties like is the MutableList empty as mentioned in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html), because it needs to be computed at the every time of the call because it can be changed.

```kotlin
class Foo {
    val check: Boolean get() = 3 % 2 == 0
}

// is equivalent to:
final class Foo {
    public final int getCheck() {
        return 3 % 2 == 0;
    }
}
```

#### In the second code:

While in the second case the field is initialized at the time of instantiation of the `Foo` class, and is stored in the memory. And it has became a runtime constant, will exist till the object is not garbage-collected.

```kotlin
class Foo {
    val check: Boolean = 3 % 2 == 0
}

// is equivalent to:
final class Foo {
    private final int check = 3 % 2 == 0;

    public final int getCheck() {
        return check;
    }
}
```

***NOTE: Unless there is a field initializer or a backing `field` keyword used in getter/setter, the property is not actually a property.***

Comment: A nitpick on the last line: as I understand it, a Kotlin property _is_ a getter method (explicit or automatically-generated; and combined with a setter if it's mutable) — even if it doesn't have a backing field.

Comment: @gidds what does that mean? `a Kotlin property is a getter method, even if it doesn't have a backing field.` I said if it does not use `field` keyword anywhere in the getter/setter and if it does not initialized directly like second code it does not exist as a property in the jvm. Reference: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields

Comment: @Aminesh That reference says that a backing field will be generated if needed.  But that's just an implementation detail.  As that page illustrates, you can have a property without a backing field, and it's just as much a property as one that has.

Answer (score 3):

An example is better than words

```
val a = 5

val b
    get() = 10
```

The decompiled code below:

```
public final class MainKt {
   private static final int a = 5;

   public static final int getA() {
      return a;
   }

   public static final int getB() {
      return 10;
   }
}
```

As you can see `get()` doesn't create a variable. This is the difference

Comment: hi , I don't think the decompiled code give as static when using val, it's just final as i know.

Comment: @AnisMARZOUK I used special tool in IDE for this, for jvm it will generate static fields because this vars are outside of any class in code

Comment: @Anis MARZOUK things defined outside a class are static, similar to how you define main function at the top-level.

Comment: @Vlad , I see now you defined the val inside a file not a class. Cause in his example he used a class, and inside a class the val become a final property.